# Add IF statement to date to know numbers of days

Tags: php, date

I need help with simple PHP code that make me headache.

in my code $date is taken from database and make that date -14 days.So i receive "echo" of date from database minus 14 days.
But how can add IF statement to "echo" that date if it is -14 days,-7 days or  0 days from today?

```
 $date=date_create("{$row['value']}");
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("-14 day"));
echo '<span id="untiltill">','Until : ',date_format($date,"d-m-Y"),'</span>';
```

example:
if date from database is (tomorrow date) 03/01/2021 then output should be

```
echo (today date)
```

but if date from database is  15/03/2021 (more than 14 days)then output should be

```
echo (that date but -14days,but no less than today)
```

if date from database is 09/01/2021 (7 days ahead from today,then output should be

```
echo (date 04/01/2021- 3 days before that date)
```

Basically,i need something like dead line,depend on date from database and display different date.
i hope you understand what im trying to say.

thank you all for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you close to what you want:

```
$row['value'] = '2021-01-20'; // demo purposes

$date_from_db = new Datetime($row['value']);

$date_minus14 = clone($date_from_db->modify('- 14 days'));

echo $date_minus14->format('d-m-Y'); // 14 days before date...

$today = new Datetime(); // Current dateTime for comparison

$diff = $date_minus14->diff($today)->d; // difference between now and -14 days in days...

echo "\n" . $diff . "\n"; // Output the number of days difference for testing purposes. 

if($diff <= 7) {
    echo $date_minus14->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

Note I've set a static value for `$row['value']` for my testing purposes. I've also used rather descriptive variable names to help you make sense of the suggested solution.

**UPDATE 1** (following comments from original poster below):

Working demo: https://www.tehplayground.com/y8K7JuKfBL1VJCCz

```
$row['value'] = '2021-01-20'; // 20th Jan 2021

$date_from_db = new Datetime($row['value']);

$today = new DateTime(); // without parameter DateTime is set to current date

// Get the number of days difference
$diff = $date_from_db->diff($today)->d;

// Check if negative or positive (past or future) - returns 0 for past
$invert = $date_from_db->diff($today)->invert;
if($invert == 0) {
    $diff = - $diff;
}

// Output the diff value for ease of understanding... try changing date at top for testing.
echo $diff . ' days from current date' . "\n";

if($diff >= 14) {
    echo '14 days (or more)';
}

if($diff == 7) {
    echo '7 days';
}

if($diff == 0) {
    echo 'Today';
}

if($diff < 0) {
    echo 'Already happened';
}
```

Comment: Your code works too,but how to change that (-14 day) in second line of my code to -7 days or today,depend on difference of both date.im new in php

Comment: This line in my code:

$date_minus14 = clone($date_from_db->modify('- 14 days'));

makes a clone of the the first date, and modifies it to be 14 days earlier. You could do similar and change the -14 days to -7 days or any other interval.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I think i do something wrong,because its not work the way it should.i mean,i want to compare date i take from database with todays date.if that difference is more than 14 days,then it should echo date 14 days,but if date is today ,it should echo today date,same if difference is 7 days.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of what the output should be for an example date?

Comment: See if this makes sense :

https://www.tehplayground.com/y8K7JuKfBL1VJCCz

I've also added an Update to my answer to try and give you clearer help.

Comment: i think its easy in PHP and i will very grateful if you can help me,because that is waay above my skills.

Comment: THANK YOU steve for help me out.,your answer work well,i just add  into each IF statement: date_add($date_from_db,date_interval_create_from_date_string("today"));
echo '($date_from_db,"d-m-Y")';

Comment: Glad that it helped & congrats for getting your code working.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference using [DateTime::diff method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$date=date_create("{$row['value']}");
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("-14 day"));
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $now->diff($date); // Giving you the differene of now and the date from database - 14 days
$diffInDays = (int)$interval->format('%R%a');
if ($diffInDays == -7 || $diffInDays == 0) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Your code work,but how to  change that (-14 day) in second line of my code to -7 days or today,depend on difference of both date.im new in php